# Meaning of monotonic in context of filters?

Tags: filters, terminology

What is meant by "monotonic" in context of filter

As shown in attached snapshot [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *monotonic* has no special meaning in the context of filters; it is used in the same way as usually. The magnitude responses of Butterworth, Chebyshev type I, and Bessel filters decrease strictly monotonically in the stopbands, i.e., the stopband attenuation increases the further you're away from the band edge.